# Get text from edit text fields that are in multiple tabs

Tags: android

I am trying to create an android application that uses tabs for an input form.  Basically I want it set up so the user can enter some information on one tab, then either submit that information, or go to another tab and enter more information and then submit the information from both tabs.

I am using the action bar and fragments to display my tabs from one activity.

If I enter text in one tab then switch to the other, then switch back, the text is still there, but I can seem to figure out how to grab the text from the tab that is not currently shown when the submit button is clicked.

Is there any way of doing this?

Ok heres my code so far.  I'm new to posting here sorry.

My tabs are set up using this:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

//initiate tabs, set text and set listeners
Tab tab = bar.newTab();
tab.setText("Details");
tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<DetailsFragment>(this, "Details", DetailsFragment.class));
bar.addTab(tab);

tab = bar.newTab();
tab.setText("Comments");
tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<CommentsFragment>(this, "Details", CommentsFragment.class));
bar.addTab(tab);
```

My TabListener:

```
private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{
private Fragment mFragment;
private final Activity mActivity;
private final String mTag;
private final Class<T> mClass;

public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz){
   mActivity = activity;
   mTag = tag;
   mClass = clz;
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
     //check if the fragment is already initialized
if(mFragment == null){
//if not, instantiate and add it to the activity
mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    }
else{
//if it exists, attach it in order to show it
ft.attach(mFragment);
}
 }
```

My on click listener:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {

            titleText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            authorText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textAuthor);
            seriesText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textSeries);
            pubText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPublisher);
            isbnText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textISBN);
            commentsText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textComments);

            String title = titleText.getText().toString();
            String author = authorText.getText().toString(); 
            String series = seriesText.getText().toString(); 
            String pub = pubText.getText().toString(); 
            String isbn = isbnText.getText().toString();
            String comments = commentsText.getText().toString();
```

My fragment classes look like this:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailsfragment, container, false);
}
```

}

and an example of their layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/detailsTab"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/textTitle" 
    android:hint="@string/textTitle" 
    android:inputType="textCapWords" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText android:id="@+id/textAuthor" 
    android:hint="@string/textAuthor" 
    android:inputType="textCapWords" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
```

If there is any other code you want to see I can post that as well.

Comment: I have tried to asign the edit text fields in the main activity in the onClick listener for the button using (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditTextField);  but that just returns null for the tab that is not currently showing.

Comment: please post your code...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out a way to get it to work how i want it to.  I doubt its the best way of doing it but heres what I did.

In the onTabUnselected in the TabListener I added a function right before I detach the fragment to check which fragment is about to be detached and then save the data to variables stored in the activity.

```
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
    if(mFragment != null)
    {
            saveData(mFragment);

            //Detach the fragment
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //do nothing
    }
}

private void saveData(Fragment frag){
    if(frag.getTag() == "Details")
    {
        titleText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        title = titleText.getText().toString();
        authorText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textAuthor);
        author = authorText.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(frag.getTag() == "Comments")
    {
        commentsText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textComments);
        comments = commentsText.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

I still feel like there has to be a better way of doing this since the data is retained when i switch between tabs in the text boxes.