# Get input from inactive tab

Tags: java, android

I have 2 tabs in my layout. I am failing to get input value entered in EditText in inactive tab. So lets say tab that holds registerLoginFragment is selected. The following code returns expected value.

```
EditText editTextEmail = (EditText)registerLoginFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
```

But getting value from 2nd tab which is inactive fails with NPE because getView() of inactive tab returns null. So following is failing:

```
EditText EditTextFirstName = (EditText)registerPersonalFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.EditTextFirstName);
```

So I need to get input from both tabs when button on 1st tab is clicked. Both tabs are visited and have values entered.

Little more code:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.getTag().toString().equals("LOGIN_TAB")){

        if(registerLoginFragment == null){
            registerLoginFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, RegisterLoginFragment.class.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.linearLayoutRegister, (Fragment)registerLoginFragment);
        }
        else{
            ft.attach((Fragment)registerLoginFragment);
        }


        currentFragment = registerLoginFragment;
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().toString().equals("PERSONAL_TAB")){
        if(registerPersonalFragment == null){
            registerPersonalFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, RegisterPersonalFragment.class.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.linearLayoutRegister, (Fragment)registerPersonalFragment);
        }
        else{
            ft.attach((Fragment)registerPersonalFragment);
        }

        currentFragment = registerPersonalFragment;
    }

}
```

So obviously this is not the right way to get values from inactive tab but I am failing to find the proper way.

I guess I can do this: [Get text from edit text fields that are in multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621831/get-text-from-edit-text-fields-that-are-in-multiple-tabs)

But is there a more "elegant" way?

Thanks
Velja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found funny way for achieving this task. Instead of detaching and attaching (or using FragmentTransaction.replace) I am showing and hiding my fragments on tab actions. Note that it is very important to use GONE value and not INVISIBLE since GONE doesn't use any space in the view: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE
I will leave question open to hear if there is still more "proper" way?
So refactored code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.getTag().toString().equals("LOGIN_TAB")){

        if(registerLoginFragment == null){
            registerLoginFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, RegisterLoginFragment.class.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.linearLayoutRegister, (Fragment)registerLoginFragment);
        }
        else{
            //ft.attach((Fragment)registerLoginFragment);
            registerLoginFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        currentFragment = registerLoginFragment;
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().toString().equals("PERSONAL_TAB")){
        if(registerPersonalFragment == null){
            registerPersonalFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, RegisterPersonalFragment.class.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.linearLayoutRegister, (Fragment)registerPersonalFragment);
        }
        else{
            //ft.attach((Fragment)registerPersonalFragment);
            registerPersonalFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        currentFragment = registerPersonalFragment;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(currentFragment != null){
        //ft.detach((Fragment)currentFragment);
        currentFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```